# Regex in spring controller

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc, routes

I am trying to build a request filter that will only get used if it matches a pattern of the letter e, then a number.  However I cannot seem to get it to work. I keep getting 400 errors every time I try something with regex.

If I just use the following it "works" but also captures mappings that do not have numbers which I don't want.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "e{number}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

I have tried the following combinations.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "e{number}",
            params = "number:\\d+",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)

@RequestMapping(value = "e{number:\d+}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)

@RequestMapping(value = "/e{^\\+?\\d+\$}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)

@RequestMapping(value = "/{^\\e+?\\d+\$}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex), you have to use something like `{varName:regex}`. There's even an example :

```
@RequestMapping("/spring-web/{symbolicName:[a-z-]+}-{version:\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d}{extension:\\.[a-z]+}")
  public void handle(@PathVariable String version, @PathVariable String extension) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. May I add another related question? Is it allowed to have other(s) variable(s) after a variable having a regex allowing many values, like /{name:.+}/bla/{othervariable}/blo/{anotherone}  In this example, what will happen if there is / inside the name ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
 @RequestMapping("/e{number:\\d+})
```

Notice the "escaped slash" before the `\d` digit specifier.

Comment: I edited the answer to remove the reference to the "solution", as such statement belongs in a comment, not in an answer. However, it would be good if you would explain in your answer (edit it) what the provided code does with respect to the question.