# How to match nested path parameter in rest url (spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, rest, path-parameter

I'd like to match a nested path of rest url, e.g. I'd like use one parameter to capture `/folder_1/folder_2/a.sh` for the following rest url. Is there any way to do that in spring boot. And BTW, I also want to match the empty path if it is `/files`. Thanks

```
/files/folder_1/folder_2/a.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `regexp` pattern using MappingRequest.
You can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18422504/19741639)